# How can I make if in match whole items of a tuple

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-3.x

If I have the code

```
if "a" in ("abc")
```

It returns True. How can I make it so that only

```
if "abc" in ("abc")
```

Returns true without using a `for` loop and **not** the first example?

Comment: `if "abc" in ("abc", "def")` is true. Did you mean to say how to make `if "a" in ("abc", "def")` True?

Comment: `"a" in ("abc", "def")` does return `False`.

Comment: @Haidro I actually wanted a way to make onle the 2nd example true and not the first, question edited

Comment: @minerz029 your first example returns false already... (despite what your question claims)

Comment: Found it, I was comparing it to a list which only had one item and Python searched it for matching characters. `if "a" in ("abc")` was True. Using `if "a" in ("abc", )` returned False

Comment: `("abc")` is a string. `("abc",)` is a tuple. `["abc"]` is a list that contains only one element, the string itself

Comment: `if ("abc") == ("abc"): Do something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
("abc")
```

isn't a tuple. Python uses parentheses for grouping as well as tuple construction (strictly speaking, the comma is the tuple construction operator). It has to decide whether this is a tuple or just grouping, and it has to pick grouping. To fix it, use

```
if "a" in ("abc",)
```

Note the comma.